# AWS Opswork environment variables in custom chef recepie

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I have successfully been able to run custom shell scripts with chef on opswork. 
However the applications environment variables is not available. I have tried to run as www-data user but the environment variables are still not available.

Is there any way to access the environment variables set in application in opswork in custom recepies?

Answer (score 0):

Acctually i found out that the environment variables are set in the sites virtualhost and is only available to the application.